# Do I need to make fields in schema.xml to use DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have many different column names and types that I want to import. Do I need to change my schema.xml to have entries for each of these specific field types, or is there a way for the importhandler to generate the schema.xml from the underlying SQL data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the fields you need to import in the schema.xml.
The DIH does not autogenerate the fields and it is better to create the fields if the amount the fields are less.

Solr also allows you to define [Dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields), where the fields need not be explicitly defined but just needs to match the regex pattern.

```
<dynamicField name="*_i"  type="integer"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

You can also define a catch field with Solr, however the behaviour cannot be control as same analysis would be applied to all the fields.